# Postgresql listen/notify

Tags: java, postgresql

Прошу помощи в реализаций одной задумки.

В общем, у меня есть база на postgre, и мне нужно ловить обновленные значения из базы. То есть когда происходит `update();`, должен срабатывать триггер, а еще я сделала функцию, которая ловит этот триггер со всеми его значениями (название измененной таблицы и значение измененной колонки). Когда запускаю через psql.exe, все прекрасно ловит и видит. А проблема у меня с клиентским приложением. Хочу, чтобы ловилось это в клиентской стороне. 
Вопрос снят, решила уже:)

Comment: Никто не сможет подсказать?

Comment: Вы бы лучше запостили ответ. Это могло бы помочь другим со схожей проблемой.